# Rearranging list in ascending order excluding delimiter

Tags: python, list

I came across a problem while trying to rearranging a list with data  that has delimiter '='.
For example:

```
list = ['1=8.06225774829855', '2=2.23606797749979', '3=8.602325267042627', '4=7.280109889280518', '5=3.1622776601683795']
```

In the end product I want my list to have number after delimiter rearranged in ascending order while keeping text before delimiter.
Expected Output:

```
['2=2.23606797749979','5=3.1622776601683795','4=7.280109889280518', '1=8.06225774829855','3=8.602325267042627']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) function to separate and extract the second number.

---

If you have

```py
list1 = ['1=8.06225774829855', '2=2.23606797749979', '3=8.602325267042627', '4=7.280109889280518', '5=3.1622776601683795']
```

You can build a new list with the [`sorted`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) function:

```py
list2 = sorted(list1, key=lambda s: float(s.split('=')[-1]))
# list2 = ['2=2.23606797749979', '5=3.1622776601683795', '4=7.280109889280518', '1=8.06225774829855', '3=8.602325267042627']
```

or sort the list it in place with [`.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

```py
list1.sort(key=lambda s: float(s.split('=')[-1]))
# list1 = ['2=2.23606797749979', '5=3.1622776601683795', '4=7.280109889280518', '1=8.06225774829855', '3=8.602325267042627']
```

---

(This is assuming that all your stings are formatted perfectly, otherwise you'll need a more complex key function.)